# Display Chinese characters in SSH terminal

Tags: encoding

I need to install a package from GitHub (https://github.com/vaxilu/x-ui/) which is pure Chinese.

I tried to install it on Ubuntu 22.04 but during installation it asks some questions and I can't use an online translator because all I see is ????????.

My current locale is as below:

```
locale -a

C
C.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

According to this question ([Ubuntu display Chinese Characters - Encoding Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070568/ubuntu-display-chinese-characters-encoding-issue)) all I need is to set my locale to utf-8, but it's already set.

When I look at the source of the `install.sh` file of the above package I clearly see the Chinese characters and I'm able to translate them, which tells me they are in utf-8 encoding.

So why I can't see them when I SSH to my Ubuntu machine?

I'm running SSH from command prompt of Windows 10.

Comment: Does the same problem happen if you run ssh from Ubuntu under WSL2? If not, this is a Windows problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same issue with Ubuntu (WSL2).

Comment: Can you try it locally without getting ssh involved? You can use the live Ubuntu installation USB to boot Ubuntu and select **Try Ubuntu** option. Then try to install the app. This will tell me if the problem is limited to ssh or it affects the local terminal as well.